# Interest rate calculation

Tags: interest-rates, finance, finance-mathematics, discounting

The task: With what interest rate given 2000 Euros after 2 years and 3000 Euros after 4 years, the actual value will be equal 4000 Euros. 
This task sounds confusing for me, I tried to calculate, but get nothing valid, so maybe I don't understand the task formulation. Here is given answer: 7.3%. 
Should I use discount interest or which method? I'm really new in this field.

Comment: You have to find the discount rate $r$, so that 2000 Euros received in 2 years and 3000 Euros received in 4 years equal 4000 Euro today, i.e. solve the equation $4000 = \frac{2000}{(1+r)^2} + \frac{3000}{(1+r)^4}$, which results in $r$ = 7.3%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :
4000= 2000/(1+**r**)^2 + 3000/(1+**r**)^4 solving this equation for **r** you'll find equals 7.30274083178438%.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had thought about this, but hadn't tried.

Answer (score 2):

Already answered, but...

```
from scipy.optimize import root

def pv(r): return 2000 / (1+r)**2 + 3000 / (1+r)**4
rate = root(lambda x: pv(x) - 4000, 0.)['x'][0]

print(f"Rate is {rate*100:.5f}%")
print(f"Present Value is {pv(rate):,.2f}")
```

Rate is 7.30274%

Present Value is 4,000.00